# Merge different data with same Id in 'TR' tag in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my current structure in the view :

[image]

Now as per the above image, the Movie 'Avengers' is having same **Movieid** in my table, but different celebs like Scarlett,Robert, etc. But the records for 'Russo' & 'Scarlett' are placed in different **Tr** tag. How can i be able to move these two records in the same **Tr** below 'Robert Jr.'.

I have tried this, but this gives me the output in the image above :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="topicList">
<thead>
    <tr><th data-priority="1"><span>Movies</span></th>
    <th data-priority="3"><span>Roles</span></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @{ int movieid = 0; }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
        <td class="topicTd">
            @if (movieid != item.MovieId)
            {
                <div class="table_home">
                    <span>@item.MovieName</span>
                </div>
            }
            @{ movieid = item.MovieId; }
        </td>

         <td>
                <div id="roles">
                    <div class="img_div">
                        <div class="rolelistTooltip">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hover right_div" data-trigger="focus" id="229759" role="button">
                                <img src="~/Content/0829.jpg" class="imgSquare img-responsive img-circle" alt="@item.CelebName">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content_img">
                        <h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hover right_div" id="229759" data-trigger="focus" role="button" tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title=""><strong class="groupID11">@item.CelebName</strong></a></h3>
                        <p>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hover right_div" id="229759" data-trigger="focus" role="button" tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title="">@item.RoleName</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </td>          
    </tr>                       
    }
</tbody>
```

This is the model : 
Int MovieId, string MovieName, int celebId, string CelebName, int roleId, string RoleName

Comment: Please add details of your model class also.

Comment: I have added the model now, @Yadukrishnan

Comment: I solved this with some logic !! Thanks anyways.